# Azure SQL Analytics tile in OMS portal doesn't show latest database immediately?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I configured the Log Analytics to single database by using the below power shell script.

```
$workspaceId = "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/REF-TODOLIST-RS-RGP/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/REF-XXXX"

$resourceId = "/subscriptions/SXXXXXX/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-EastUS/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/XXXXx/databases/Research_db"

Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $ResourceId  -WorkspaceId $workspaceId -Enabled $true
```

When I run the power shell script successfully, but in OMS portal of Azure SQL Analytics tile doesn’t show the latest database.

Answer (score 1):

I had  similar Issue , i would suggest to enable this with GUI on Azure Portal , Disable it and Enable it again . 
Also Enable Metrics and SQL Insights Logs which you do it Using GUI

Ref 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-metrics-diag-logging

Many Thanks 
Arun